# Frame rate changes with respect to window size

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I was just experimenting with **opengl** when I observed that the frame rate changes when the window is enlarged or compressed. I observed that  for 301 frames  it takes 60.116 FPS and for 3000 frames it takes about 6043 FPS. SO as you enlarge the window the FPS also increases? Does this have anything to do with **refresh rate**?

Answer (score 0):

No. The term you're looking for is **fillrate**. To make a long story short: The bigger the window the more pixels the GPU has to touch, which simply takes longer.